# Cant get fadeIn() to work when page loads jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fade in a container using jQuery on page load. However, I seem to be unsuccessful. The code that I am using is below.

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-first" id="col-first">
    <div class = "content">
        <p class="contentHeader">What we do</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#col-first").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Script tags in the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

EDIT

CSS file:
I have tried both

```
#col-first{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

AND

```
#col-first{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be the element invisible first to be able to see it fading in? see example: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#entry-examples

Comment: I have just set it to hidden but still no joy

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: I tried both display: none; and visibility: hidden;

Comment: Do you have any js errors on your browser console? from your code I can't see referencing jquery

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:1

Comment: you need to use the jquery CDN

Comment: aha, here you go, you are calling a jQuery function without referencing jQuery

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have that in my code. Its in the original post, under script tags in the head

Comment: no you added angular not jquery

Comment: So I did. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

fadeIn works on hidden elements so your code wont work. you will have to make it display none or hidden by default
i linked a fiddle below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q0uypfj4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out I think that's what you're looking for :

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script> 
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#col-first").hide();
                        $("#col-first").fadeToggle(1000);
                    });
            </script>         
    </head>

    <div class="col-first" id="col-first">
    <div class = "content">
        <p class="contentHeader">What we do</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the solution, I had the wrong library in.